# Use pycurl without installation

Tags: python, pycurl

I am working on a tkinter app and I would like to use the pycurl module in my project but without being installed on any host machine... Like a portable version into my package.
I didn't see any topic on the web speaking about it but still keeping hope to have a sort of workaround for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered creating a binary of our source code using something like `pyinstaller` ?

Comment: I never heard of it but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a binary file of your project using `pyinstaller`. It will bundle all the dependencies that are required by your application, users can just run the binary file without worrying about installing or setting up dependencies.

Comment: Thank Arun, I look for it. Nice advice.